# ¿Puedo desarrollar aplicaciones hibridas(moviles) y consumir un web service?

Tags: app

Tengo una duda y me ha surgido la idea de desarrollar  apps de información en la cual desearía subirlo a las tiendas de apps tanto de ios y android, entonces unas de mis preguntas es:
¿Que framework me recomendarían?
Tengo ganas de desarrollarlo usando tecnologías de js, html, css.

- ¿Alguien ha tenido experiencias en estos desarrollos para que haga conexión a una base de datos, y es posible que funcione?
- ¿Desarrollar estas apps, en caso de android, cualquier versión de lo soportaría?¿Lo mismo pasaría con ios?

Ya que mi aplicación solo consiste en crear un listview. 
Necesito ayuda apenas y entiendo de esto ya que se me haría mas fácil el desarrollarlo que estar haciéndolo de forma nativa y peor aun que no cuento con una mac, y he investigado como desarrollarlo en windows pero no me funciona. Graicas espero sus sugerencias si han trabajado con algo similar

Comment: Si quieres hacer uso de tecnologías html, css y js, puedes hacer uso de IONIC o React Native. Por otro lado, Flutter es una muy buena alternativa pero utiliza el lenguaje de programación Dart, el cual es muy parecido a Java y a Javascript.

Comment: con flutter se puede crear tantos el apk y el otro de ios al mismo tiempo con el mismo proyecto? en caso de usarlo, crees que no haya problemas de compatibilidad por las versiones de android por ejemplo?

Comment: Cuando Flutter compila, te genera el código fuente para ambos sistemas operativos, si quieres después puedes abrir ese código en Android Studio o Xcode y ver el código que se genero. En cuando a compatibilidad de versiones te mentiría si te digo que si o no.  Pero te recomiendo investigues sobre Flutter. Puede ser una muy buena alternativa.

Comment: Lo tomare en cuenta porque he estado investigando y no encontre casi nada de eso, por eso mismo hacia la pregunta para saber sus experiencias. Pero no sabia que en Flutter podia hacer la compilación para los dos, y el tema de compatibilidad es la que me preocupa mas, ya que a la hora de desarrollar y que solo funcione para las versiones mas recientes seria un fracaso a las horas sometidas

Comment: Es un buen punto a tomar en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Una primera [lectura](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-end_y_back-end) que le recomiendo es sobre la distinción entre *front-end* y *back-end*, puesto que a la hora de trabajar con bases de datos, dependiendo de cuál sea su enfoque, tal vez le interese atender a este patrón de diseño.

Una aplicación híbrida se desarrolla típicamente utilizando HTML, CSS y JavaScript. Después, podría utilizar una herramienta como Cordova para inserirla en un contenedor nativo y publicarla en los catálogos de las respectivas plataformas, además de para obtener acceso a las funcionalidades de los dispositivos finales.

Ionic es un *framework* para con estos propósitos que cuenta con mucho renombre. Le recomiendo echar un vistazo a su [documentación](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/). En verdad, Ionic suele enmascarar otro *framework* ampliamente conocido en este campo como lo es [Angular](https://angular.io), aunque también podría funcionar sobre React o Vue.js.

No obstante lo anterior, si usted no tiene experiencia previa desarrollando con estas tecnologías, mi recomendación es que trate de ganar cierta soltura con HTML, CSS y JavaScript antes de lanzarse al uso de *frameworks* de mayor calado. Este [tutorial](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-html) es un buen comienzo.

Los anteriormente expuestos *frameworks* cuentan con abstracciones de alto nivel para facilitar el **manejo** de bases de datos.

Otras tecnologías interesantes y relacionadas, aunque ligeramente divergentes con su perspectiva, serían:

- [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), un *framework* Python que le permite crear sitios web abstrayéndole casi totalmente del diseño del *back-end*.
- [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/), un SDK que le permite crear, usando el lenguaje Dart, apps "pseudonativas" simultáneamente compatibles con iOS y Android.

Comment: Entiendo perfectamente lo del front-end y back-end, ya que he desarrollado sistemas web usando framework como laravel con vue, en este caso toda esa parte la domino perfectamente, mi duda siempre sera ahora aplciar lo mismos conocimientos para el desarrollo de apps moviles, lo cual nunca he hecho pero si he escuchado que usando lo mismo de html,css, y js es posible . La cuestión aqui es saber sus experiencias, ya que cuento con poco tiempo para aprender el desarrollo movil y al final no funcione lo que requiero, seria una perdida de tiempo

Comment: También otra de mis dudas es con respecto a la compatibilidad de estas apps generadas por los framework, me causa intriga saber que solo sea compatible con versiones recientes o viceversa

Comment: Acerca de la compatibilidad es difícil generalizar porque se trata de una cuestión completamente específica para cada framework. Una vez haya escogido usted con el que desea trabajar podrá encontrar ese detalle en su documentación. No obstante, normalmente los avances en estas librerías se van integrando de forma que permitan a los potenciales usuarios una transición holgada de sus dispositivos. Sólo en los realmente desactualizados se originarían problemas graves y viene a ser algo normal. Yo sinceramente no me preocuparía demasiado por este punto.